# html5 audio player flash fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I need a html5 mp3 player that support playlists. The biggest thing is that it has to have a flash fallback to support firefox because I will only be using .mp3 as my source. Heres the catch...it has to work locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jPlayer is an html5 player with flash fallback, that also supports playlists.

I have a blog entry describing how to get it going (invisibly) [here](http://vigrond.com/blog/2011/12/01/invisible-html5-flash-audio-player-using-jplayer/)

You can consult the documentation if you are interested in a visual playlist.

http://jplayer.org/

Comment: but will it play a mp3 in firefox LOCALLY?

Comment: because of flash security issues.